# search and find from csv with dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file containing info like this:

```
1087,c6d537e112156be1afbb8a5a85221ff4d95e2461f83f03425549ff42dee7a278
```

I also have a dictionary in python containing similar info :

```
{'danial': '277375b99e186c72ac38ac47b03199038342fe0389be8765476fa2be0c5b5649', 'elham': 'c6d537e112156be1afbb8a5a85221ff4d95e2461f83f03425549ff42dee7a278'}
```

how can I search values of dict in my csv file and print matching row in CSV to keys in dictionary in out put
for example :

```
danial,1087
elham,1011
```

Comment: shouldn't it be switched? like `elham,1087`

Comment: i'd probably read the csv into another dict, then go through and compare values, make new dict where they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

1. Create another, inverted dictionary which maps your values to their keys:

```
inverted_dict = { hash_string : key for key, hash_string in YOUR_DICT.items() }
```

2. Open your csv file, iterate the lines of it, and extract the first and second elements of each line:

```
with open(YOUR_CSV_FILENAME) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        val, hash_string = line.strip().split()
```

3. Check if the second element is in your inverted dict, and if so, print the appropriate mapping:

```
        if hash_string in inverted_dict:
            print(f"{inverted_dict[hash_string]}, {val}")
```